# Problemas al renderizar circularprogressbar dentro de un recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un proyecto en el cual en un recyclerview tengo que mostrar cierto porcentaje en forma de un circularprogressbar, el problema que se tiene es que al momento de mostrar los progressbar los primeros porcentaje al pasarlos por código los renderiza bien, pero al hacer el scroll los finales NO los renderiza y al momento se subir algunos si los renderiza bien y otros no, el porcentaje es variado en ciertas ocasiones para este caso todos tienen que tener un porcentaje de 100, aqui dejo como lo estoy haciendo

RESULTADO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi **onBindViewHolder**

```
DataResult result = data.get(position);

    String participation = result.getParticipationString()+"%";

    if(result.getMargin() <= 0){
        holder.txtValue.setText(result.getMargin()+"");
        holder.prG.setProgressDrawable(ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.color_progres_red));
        holder.txtPor.setText(participation);
        setColorRunnable(100,holder);
    }else if(result.getMargin() > 0 && result.getMargin() <= 25){
        holder.txtValue.setText(result.getMargin()+"");
        holder.prG.setProgressDrawable(ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.color_progres_orange));
        holder.txtPor.setText(participation);
        setColorRunnable(result.getMargin(),holder);
    }else if(result.getMargin() >= 26 && result.getMargin() <= 50){
        holder.txtValue.setText(result.getMargin()+"");
        holder.prG.setProgressDrawable(ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.color_progres_yellow));
        holder.txtPor.setText(participation);
        setColorRunnable(result.getMargin(),holder);
    }else if(result.getMargin() >= 51 && result.getMargin() <= 100){
        holder.txtValue.setText(result.getMargin()+"");
        holder.prG.setProgressDrawable(ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.color_progres_green));
        holder.txtPor.setText(participation);
        setColorRunnable(result.getMargin(),holder);
    }

    String name = result.getName().toLowerCase();

    holder.txtName.setText(name);
    holder.txtGn.setText(Utils.toCurrencyValue(result.getGain()));

    SimpleImageLoader.with(holder.imgG, result.getThumbnailImage(), R.mipmap.ic_image_preparation );
```

Este es mi método que ayuda a renderizar el porcentaje

```
private void setColorRunnable(int variable, MarginDataHolder holder){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            holder.prG.setProgress(variable);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(16);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("ERROR_VIEW",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```